# Suppress distributed.worker - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm running a dask LocalCluster with 44 workers on a 44 core linux machine.
The program runs totally fine, however there is a constant stream of:

`distributed.worker - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high...` warnings.

I have set the env variable `MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_` to 0.

Nothing fails. The [documentation](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/worker-memory.html) makes me believe it is a false positive warning.

Is there a way of suppressing the constant stream of this one particular warning, without raising the `silence_logs` parameter?